# The error webview on ios

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

My application is webview. 
The normal it load page http://staging.nhomxe.vn. 
But when server send a notify, and attachmented a link. Webview will open this link.

My application activity normal. Then, i add Navigation Controller to ViewControler. 
When Server send notify, my webview notify error at [vc.webView loadRequest:urlRequest]; , and application auto exit.

My code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert|UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
UILocalNotification *localNotif =
[launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];

if (localNotif) {
    // launched from notification
    NSLog(@"Co notify!!!");
    NSString *message = [localNotif valueForKey:@"link"];
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setValue:message forKey:@"LINK"];

} else {
    // from the springboard
    NSLog(@"Khong co notify!!!");

}
return YES;
}



- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{

}
- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
NSLog(@"My token: %@",deviceToken);
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:deviceToken forKey:@"TOKEN"];
}

- (void) application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
 NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}


- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
// Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

 - (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
// Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:
(NSDictionary*)userInfo
{
NSURL *url ;
NSLog(@"Received notification: %@", userInfo);
NSDictionary *data = [ userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"];
for(NSString *key in data) {
    NSString *info = [data objectForKey:key];
    NSLog(@"thong tin nhan dc: %@ : %@", key, info);
}

NSString *message = [userInfo valueForKey:@"link"] ;
//NSArray *info = [message componentsSeparatedByString:@"&@"];
//NSString *body = [info objectAtIndex:0];
//NSString *link = [info objectAtIndex:1];
NSLog(@"Thong tin Link: %@",message);
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:message forKey:@"LINK"];
ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
if(message == NULL)
{
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://staging.nhomxe.vn"];
}else
{
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:message];
}

NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[vc.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
[vc.webView3 loadRequest:urlRequest];


}

@end
```

My error:

```
2014-08-28 14:51:59.374 NhomXe[30379:907] Thong tin Link: http://staging.nhomxe.vn/org/instance_message/conversation-detail.xhtml?post=13001628&orgId=190000168@vehicletracking
2014-08-28 14:52:14.950 NhomXe[30379:907] -[UINavigationController webView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d5c8350
2014-08-28 14:52:14.958 NhomXe[30379:907] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController webView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1d5c8350'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x314e22a3 0x3913e97f 0x314e5e07 0x314e4531 0x3143bf68 0xd687f 0x3353d585 0x3353dfa5 0x33f53305 0x314b7173 0x314b7117 0x314b5f99 0x31428ebd 0x31428d49 0x34fa52eb 0x3333e301 0xd6ad9 0x39575b20)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Your rootViewController is returning a [UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which is used to manage a navigation stack, that is represented by an array of view controllers.

To get your view controller try getting the topViewController, for example:

```
UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;

ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
```

You can also get a array of all view controller that navigation manages by:

```
NSLog(@"%@", navigationController.viewControllers);
```

Update your UI on the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // make sure vc is a weak refernace to avoid retain cycle 
    [vc.webView loadRequest:urlRequest];
    [vc.webView3 loadRequest:urlRequest];
});
```

Comment: i use ViewController *vc = (ViewController *)self.window.rootViewController.modalViewController;
My application don't notify error. but webView don't reload link from notify.

Comment: see if the website is initialized.

Comment: My webview don't activity. it only show curent page.

Comment: that because didReceiveRemoteNotification is called in the background thread use GCD to call in main thread. see edit

Comment: Thank you! my webView running normal. ah, i have a problem. When server send notify to client will have two case:
case 1: My application has closed.
in this case, i click to notify, my webview will open link attachmented success.
case 2: My application running at background by click Home key on ios device.
if use my code, webview open link success when click to notify, but have a problem is when application running and have a notify from server, webview will auto reload link. User will don't like this.

Comment: you probably need to notify your user about page refresh

Comment: if i alert for user,In a case application running is normal.But application run background, when have a notify from server. i click to notify, my application will repeat a alert.